# How can I sort a 2-D array in MATLAB with respect to 2nd row?

Tags: sorting, matlab

I have array say "a"

a =

```
 1     4     5
 6     7     2
```

if i use function
b=sort(a)

gives ans

b =

```
 1     4     2
 6     7     5
```

but i want ans like

b =

```
 5     1     4
 2     6     7
```

mean 2nd row should be sorted but elements of ist row should remain unchanged and should be correspondent to row 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

sortrows(a',2)'

Pulling this apart:

```
a =  1     4     5
     6     7     2

a' = 1 6
     4 7
     5 2

sortrows(a',2) = 5 2
                 1 6
                 4 7

sortrows(a',2)' = 5 1 4
                  2 6 7
```

The key here is sortrows sorts by a specified row, all the others follow its order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) function on just the second row, then use the index output to sort the whole array:

```
[junk,sortIndex] = sort(a(2,:));
b = a(:,sortIndex);
```

Comment: junk can be replaced with:

[~, sortIndex]  This is a little cleaner in newer versions of MATLAB

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very not backward compatible, and can be horribly embarrassing when you code for users who use slightly older versions of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
a = [1 4 5; 6 7 2]
a =
     1     4     5
     6     7     2
>> [s,idx] = sort(a(2,:))
s =
     2     6     7
idx =
     3     1     2
>> b = a(:,idx)
b =
     5     1     4
     2     6     7
```

in other words, you use the second argument of `sort` to get the sort order you want, and then you apply it to the whole thing.