# Matlab - sorting a matrix

Tags: sorting, matlab

I think I can illustrate this best with an example:
Suppose I have A = [ 1, 4, 2, 3;
                     0,-1, 2, -1]

I want to turn it into
[1, 2, 3,  4;
0, 2, -1, -1]

i.e. keep columns intact, sort by entries in first row. How do I do this?

Comment: Often duplicated: [How can I sort a 2-D array in MATLAB with respect to one column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134712/how-can-i-sort-a-2-d-array-in-matlab-with-respect-to-one-column), [How do I maintain rows when sorting a matrix in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923118/how-do-i-maintain-rows-when-sorting-a-matrix-in-matlab), [How can I sort a 2-D array in MATLAB with respect to 2nd row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482958/how-can-i-sort-a-2-d-array-in-matlab-with-respect-to-2nd-row)

Answer (score 2):

The [sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) command does what you want:

```
>> A = [ 1, 4, 2, 3; 0,-1, 2, -1];
>> sortrows(A.').'   

ans =

     1     2     3     4
     0     2    -1    -1
```

You can also use the second return value from `sort` to get the column permutation necessary to turn your matrix into the one you want:

```
>> [~,ii] = sort(A(1,:))

ii =

     1     3     4     2

>> A(:,ii)

ans =

     1     2     3     4
     0     2    -1    -1
```