# Sort rows of a matrix in ascending order

Tags: matlab, sorting

I would like to sort a matrix in ascending order, however I do not want to affect the third column. For example, the sorted version of

```
A= [ 2 1 3; 
     5 4 1; 
     4 3 2]
```

Would be

```
B= [1 2 3; 
    4 5 1; 
    3 4 2]
```

Comment: Seeing [double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5347377/958580) ? Use the search ! Double agents don't get badges :P (Though being SO they probably will, dual horned unicorns are not uncommon)

Answer (score 2):

Matlab provides quite a bit of inhouse help so using `help FUNCTION/CLASS` would have provided you with the below information. If you don't know the `FUNCTION\CLASS` name use `lookfor TERM` for a list of matches or alternately  `docsearch TERM`.

Stock matlab provides both `sort` and `sortrows`. You'll be needing the latter.

```
sortrows(X,C)
```

Where C is a list of column indices to sort by  whose sign may be positive corresponding for ascending order or negative for descending order.

In your example you'll want this :

```
sortrows(A',[1,2])'
```

The `'` indicates to matlab that you need the matrix transposed, which basically swaps rows and columns before and after `sortrows` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort the 1st two columns and update the matrix accordingly:

*edit*: updated dimension

```
A(:,1:2) = sort(A(:,1:2),2);
```

Comment: I think you'll want to specify the dimension to be 2.  The OP wants to sort along the rows without affecting the last column.

Comment: yes sir, you're right, i just want to make the rows in ascending order but 3rd column should not be affected.